# Pycharm: how to set a custom string function (ie Type Renderer) for external object types?

Tags: python, debugging, types, pycharm, lxml

Is it possible to configure PyCharm to use a custom function to display the `__str__` representation of a type in a debug session? I am referring to built-in types or types imported from third party libraries which I would rather not modify.

For example, instead of a string in the debugger like `{lxml.html.HtmlElement} <Element tr at 0x10e2c1418>` I would like to have the output of `etree.tostring(element)`.

Intellij Idea has *[Java Type Renderers](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/04/type-renderers/)* where you can set a custom `toString()` method for any type, so that during debugging those types will use your custom `toString()` renderers. Is similar functionality available or achievable in PyCharm?

I tried this approach:

```
# for lxml.html

lxml.html.HtmlElement.__str__ = lxml.html.etree.tostring
```

This gives the expected result for `lxml.html`, but it feels like an ugly workaround, and I would like to find a way to do it that does not require [monkey-patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) external libraries.

The downside of this approach is that it doesn't work for example with `lxml.etree.Element` because setting `lxml.etree.Element.__str__ = lxml.etree.tostring` has no effect, as it delegates to `lxml.etree._Element` which is C native module with a read-only `__str__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature for Python, please vote for the corresponding ticket in PyCharms' bug tracker: [PY-21984](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21984).